# Weird character encoding when submitting form

Tags: php

I am submitting a form via GET and weirdly é is being converted to %c3%a9.

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: @zerkms I noticed it, but was unable to remove my comment. now removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how that character is presented in UTF-8: as 2 bytes: `0xC3` and `0xA9`

References:

- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm
- http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ (search for `U+00E9`)